# TabControl, TabItem, UserControl gets focus

Tags: wpf

I have TabControl with TabItem's.

I have UserControl displayed on selected TabItem. I have ComboBox (with GotFocus="UserControl_GotFocus") on my UserControl.

I want to catch event when my UserControl gets focus.

This is my approach:

```
private void UserControl_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    EventTypeSelection.Items.Add("Focus catched!");

}
```

The problem here is that UserControl_GotFocus gets called everytime I select item on my ComboBox.

1. What is the proper solution for my problem?
2. What is the best solution if I wanted to catch Focus event only when it happens for the first time?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Boolean parameter to register if it is the first time that the `GotFocus`handler has been called:

```
private isFirstTime = true;

private void UserControl_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (isFirstTime) 
    {
        EventTypeSelection.Items.Add("Focus caught!");
        isFirstTime = false;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could move monitor the `GotFocus` event on the `UserControl` instead of handling the event on the `ComboBox`.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! GotFocus event is set on UserControl not on ComboBox.